# Pass through variable in Spring boot / Thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am looking for a way to pass the whole object through without having to use `<input type="hidden" />` on the different variables. It seems like the th:object will not carry over the incoming information on the "whole object"

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/api/result/save}" th:object="${result}" th:method="post">
<!--- Input fields -->
<input type="hidden" th:field="${result}"> <---- Not working. 
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="spara">Spara</button>

From the model I have
Result result = new Result(teams);
result.setTeam1ID(aTeam1.get().getId()); // This variable will not be changed in the HTML so I would like to pass that to the next page
// Other variables
```

When I get to the /save the Result will only contain variables set in Thymeleaf it will not retain the information from the original model above.

```
@PostMapping("/save")
    public RedirectView saveResult(Result result, Model model) {

      service.saveResult(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thymeleaf is use to generate view, you can store some variable but not the whole object.

Though you can try these method:

1. If you object is already stored at server-side in memory or data base. You just pass the unique key of that object get it back using hidden input type.
2. Store the object into session then get it from there whenever requered.